Firefox frequently crashes on Ubuntu 22.04
Firefox frequently crashes on my machine.
If I were to quantify it, I would say it crashes once every 20-30 minutes of usage.
These crashes happen regardless of the web sites in current use or tabs open.
From what I've read so far on FF crashes, it is commonly suggested to set hardware acceleration to false in settings. I tried this and it made no difference.
The crash log seems to suggest that Firefox is encountering errors related to nvidia graphics. In particular, it seems related to my machine having dual GPUs. Here is the crash report log line I am using as reference:
GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: More than 2 GPUs detected via PCI, secondary GPU is arbitrary

Please see the (truncated) crash log below.
This problem is so severe I will likely migrate to a chromium-based browser, as I've never experienced crashes on them on my machine before.
System info:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.5.0-45-generic
Firefox Browser Extended Support Release (ESR): 115.13.0esr
Nvidia driver version (proprietary/official): 550.90.07


The crash log:
AdapterDriverVendor: nvidia/unknown
AdapterDriverVersion: 550.90.7.0
AvailablePageFile: 46387621888
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 113696120832
AvailableSwapMemory: 2147479552
AvailableVirtualMemory: 123288117248
BackgroundTaskMode: 0
BuildID: 20240703222632
ContentSandboxCapabilities: 119
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 4
CrashTime: 1723010662
DOMFissionEnabled: 1
DOMIPCEnabled: 1
DesktopEnvironment: ubuntu:gnome
EMCheckCompatibility: true
EventLoopNestingLevel: 1
ExperimentalFeatures: browser.startup.homepage.abouthome_cache.enabled,devtools.inspector.compatibility.enabled
GpuSandboxLevel: 0
GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: More than 2 GPUs detected via PCI, secondary GPU is arbitrary
 (t=0.264141) 
GraphicsNumActiveRenderers: 20
GraphicsNumRenderers: 24
HeadlessMode: 0
InstallTime: 1720686395
IsWayland: 0
LastStartupWasCrash: 0
LinuxUnderMemoryPressure: 0
Notes: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTSFP(D00-L1110-W0000000-T010) Has dual GPUs. GPU #2: AdapterVendorID2: 0x1002, AdapterDeviceID2: 0x164eWR! WR+ EGL? EGL- GL Context? GL Context+ WebGL? WebGL+ 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
RDDProcessStatus: Running
ReleaseChannel: esr115
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 18279
StartupCacheValid: 1
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1723002596
SubmittedFrom: Client
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 136290394112
TotalPhysicalMemory: 134142914560
UptimeTS: 8066.675371
UtilityProcessStatus: Running
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 115.13.0


So I'm not alone. Have you found a fix for this yet @Alnitak?
